# Ubuntu freezing

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics, bug-reporting, amd-processor

so I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I have been having this big problem. The system just freezes randomly, the sound stops completely and the only way to fix it is to restart the pc, but of course it happens again. I have AMD processor and graphics card. Also I tried downloading some drivers but it doesn't seem to be the case, or I didn't do it right, which is possible because I am new to Ubuntu. Does anyone have a fix for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was BIOS. I updated BIOS to beta version that came out in 2020, stable version didn't work. Can't be sure this was the problem but for few hours the Ubuntu didn't freeze.